# An example of a function whose domain is the set of positive integers and range is the set of integers?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I was browsing through one of my old pre-calc books, and I feel a bit ashamed to say I can't think of a simple answer.  It intuitively feels impossible, as there are half as many points in the domain as there are in the range... Any clever answers out there?  Thanks!

Comment: Map them successively to $0$, $1$, $-1$, $2$, $-2$, $\ldots$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zero maps to zero. All even numbers $n$ map to $n/2$ and all odd numbers $n$ map to $-(\frac{n-1}{2}+1).$ This map is one to one and onto and hence invertible.

Answer (score 0):

Map $n$ to the difference of the number of factors $2$ and $3$ in the prime factorization of $n$.